# Define custom loss (perceptual loss) in CNN autoencoder with pre-train vgg19 tensorflow,Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, autoencoder

i want to define perceptual_loss in autoencoder that build in keras.
my autoencoder is look like this :

Encoder:

```
input_encoder = Input((32,32,3),name = 'encoder_input')
encoder = Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation = 'relu',name = 'encoder_layer1')(input_encoder)
encoder = Flatten(name = 'encoder_layer2')(encoder)
latent_encoding = Dense(128 , activation = 'relu', name = 'encoder_layer3')(encoder)

Encoder = Model(inputs= [input_encoder], outputs=[latent_encoding],name = 'Encoder')
```

Decoder :

```
input_decoder = Input(128,name = 'decoder_input')
decoder = Reshape((1, 1, 128),name = 'decoder_layer1')(input_decoder)
decoder = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2,2), activation='relu' , name = 'decoder_layer2')(decoder)
decoder = UpSampling2D(8 ,name = 'decoder_layer3')(decoder)
decoder = Conv2DTranspose(3, (9,9), activation='relu' , name = 'decoder_layer2')(decoder)

Decoder = Model(inputs= [input_decoder], outputs=[decoder ],name = 'Decoder')
```

AutoEncoder :

```
input = Input((32,32,3),name = 'input')
latent = Encoder(input)
output = Decoder(latent)
AE = Model(inputs= [input], outputs=[output ],name = 'AE')
```

now i define new loss function perceptual_loss with pretrain vgg19 like this i get input image and reconstruct image to pre-train vgg19 and get result from some layer of vgg19 and then i use subtract of two vectors as error of that layer in vgg19 and then i use weighted sum of layer's error to calculate total error :

```
selected_layers = ['block1_conv1', 'block2_conv2',"block3_conv3" ,'block4_conv3','block5_conv4']
selected_layer_weights = [1.0, 4.0 , 4.0 , 8.0 , 16.0]

def perceptual_loss(input_image , reconstruct_image):
    vgg = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(32,32,3))
    vgg.trainable = False

    outputs = [vgg.get_layer(l).output for l in selected_layers]
    model = Model(vgg.input, outputs)

    h1_list = model(input_image)
    h2_list = model(reconstruct_image)

    rc_loss = 0.0

    for h1, h2, weight in zip(h1_list, h2_list, selected_layer_weights):
        h1 = K.batch_flatten(h1)
        h2 = K.batch_flatten(h2)
        rc_loss = rc_loss + weight * K.sum(K.square(h1 - h2), axis=-1)

    return rc_loss
```

and then i compile AE:

```
rmsprop = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.00025)
AE.compile(loss= perceptual_loss, optimizer= rmsprop)
```

but when i want fit AE:

```
history = AE.fit(train_images, train_images,
                          epochs= 2,
                          verbose=1)
```

i get error

> ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.

please help me . thank you

## update :

i update the loss function by answer of @Mr. For Example but i get new error :
now i have loss function :

```
'''
define perceptual_loss
'''

selected_layers = ['block1_conv1', 'block2_conv2',"block3_conv3" ,'block4_conv3','block5_conv4']
selected_layer_weights = [1.0, 4.0 , 4.0 , 8.0 , 16.0]

vgg = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(32,32,3))
vgg.trainable = False
outputs = [vgg.get_layer(l).output for l in selected_layers]
model = Model(vgg.input, outputs)

def perceptual_loss(input_image , reconstruct_image):
    h1_list = model(input_image)
    h2_list = model(reconstruct_image)

    rc_loss = 0.0
    for h1, h2, weight in zip(h1_list, h2_list, selected_layer_weights):
        h1 = K.batch_flatten(h1)
        h2 = K.batch_flatten(h2)
        rc_loss = rc_loss + weight * K.sum(K.square(h1 - h2), axis=-1)

    return rc_loss
```

i get new error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-16-3133696ab8be> in <module>()
----> 1 VAE.fit(train_images[:5],train_images[:5],epochs=2,verbose=1)

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    862       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    863       if self._created_variables:
--> 864         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"
    865                          " decorated with tf.function.")
    866       return results

ValueError: Creating variables on a non-first call to a function decorated with tf.function.
```

## update 2

as @Navid said i add `@tf.function`  before my loss function and the error is gone!

````
'''
define perceptual_loss
'''

selected_layers = ['block1_conv1', 'block2_conv2',"block3_conv3" ,'block4_conv3','block5_conv4']
selected_layer_weights = [1.0, 4.0 , 4.0 , 8.0 , 16.0]

vgg = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(32,32,3))
vgg.trainable = False
outputs = [vgg.get_layer(l).output for l in selected_layers]
model = Model(vgg.input, outputs)

@tf.function
def perceptual_loss(input_image , reconstruct_image):
    h1_list = model(input_image)
    h2_list = model(reconstruct_image)

    rc_loss = 0.0
    for h1, h2, weight in zip(h1_list, h2_list, selected_layer_weights):
        h1 = K.batch_flatten(h1)
        h2 = K.batch_flatten(h2)
        rc_loss = rc_loss + weight * K.sum(K.square(h1 - h2), axis=-1)

    return rc_loss ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create the model outside of the loss function and use `@tf.function` before the definition of loss function.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create the model inside the loss function, instead you should do something like:

```
selected_layers = ['block1_conv1', 'block2_conv2',"block3_conv3" ,'block4_conv3','block5_conv4']
selected_layer_weights = [1.0, 4.0 , 4.0 , 8.0 , 16.0]

vgg = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(32,32,3))
vgg.trainable = False
outputs = [vgg.get_layer(l).output for l in selected_layers]
model = Model(vgg.input, outputs)

@tf.function
def perceptual_loss(input_image , reconstruct_image):
    h1_list = model(input_image)
    h2_list = model(reconstruct_image)

    rc_loss = 0.0
    for h1, h2, weight in zip(h1_list, h2_list, selected_layer_weights):
        h1 = K.batch_flatten(h1)
        h2 = K.batch_flatten(h2)
        rc_loss = rc_loss + weight * K.sum(K.square(h1 - h2), axis=-1)

    return rc_loss
```

Comment: I update the code as you said but get a new error that very similar to the previous error.

Comment: i add ```@tf.function``` before the loss function  and problem is solved. thank you.

Comment: @alish my mistake, forgot that one, the `tf.function` converts a Python function to its graph representation for faster computation, so you can using it whenever you define the loss function